# Perl RawIP maximum data size

Tags: perl, networking

I'm trying to send some data over TCP using Net::RawIP in Perl. Unfortunately i get the error

> sendto() at /usr/lib/x86_64-linus-gnu/perl5/5.24/Net/RawIP.pm line 630

if the TCP data field is bigger than about 1470 characters:

```
  my $n = Net::RawIP->new({
                        ip  => {
                                saddr => '[src]',
                                daddr => '[dst]',
                               },
                        tcp => {
                                source => 7777,
                                dest   => 7777,
                                data => "x" x 150  
                          }
                       });
  $n->send;
```

works, but

```
  my $n = Net::RawIP->new({
                        ip  => {
                                saddr => '[src]',
                                daddr => '[dst]',
                               },
                        tcp => {
                                source => 7777,
                                dest   => 7777,
                                data => "x" x 1500  # size changed here
                          } 
                       });
  $n->send;
```

crashes. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: @toolic, That's the module's fault. (`croak("sendto()");` in `util.c`)

Comment: You are correct, with `strace` i get `EMSGSIZE (Message too long)`. I set the MTU to automatic (also tested really high values) via the network manager, but still get the error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're building a packet that's [too large](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit), so `sendto` is returning error `EMSGSIZE`.

> EMSGSIZE
>   The socket type requires that message be sent atomically, and the size of the message to be sent made this impossible.

It's no mystery it starts failing around 1500; that's the maximum an Ethernet frame can carry.

You need to use multiple packets or multiple packet fragments.